# Generics in Hierarchical Model Issue

Tags: java, generics

I have following hierarchy of classes:

```
public interface Table<V> {

    Map<String, Object> getNamedParams(SearchQuery<V> query);

}
```

```
public class TopicTable implements Table<Topic> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getNamedParams(TopicSearchQuery query) {
        // TODO to be implemented
        return null;
    }

}
```

```
@Data
public abstract class SearchQuery<E> {

    private Integer pageSize;
    private Integer pageNumber;

}
```

```
public class TopicSearchQuery extends SearchQuery<Topic> {

    private String orgId;
    private Boolean isShared;
    private String name;
    private String description;

}
```

My IDE is complaining that the method `getNamedParams` from interface `Table` is not properly implemented in class `TopicTable`. I know it has something to do with inheritance and my usage of generics. 
What I am trying to accomplish: tie entity, search query and table together, so that table operates only with proper entities and search queries. I want this to be cohesive and robust. Any idea on how I can achieve it best, so that the design is not cluttered or cumbersome, ideally, with no explicit casting. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Imagine I have a `Table<Topic>`, I should be able to give it any `SearchQuery<V>`. Your implementation only allows `TopicSearchQuery` specifically. It is more restrictive than the interface it claims to implement, thus it does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method signature:

```
getNamedParams(TopicSearchQuery query)
```

Does not override the method. It would have to be:

```
getNamedParams(SearchQuery<Topic> query)
```

You can't change the type of the parameter to be any more specific (because this would violate Liskov substitutability) or less specific (because Java doesn't allow it when overriding) than required by the interface.

---

If you want to be able to require a more specific parameter type, add another type variable:

```
public interface Table<V, SQ extends SearchQuery<V>> {
  Map<String, Object> getNamedParams(SQ query); 
}
```

Then you can declare your implementing class to use that type:

```
public class TopicTable implements Table<Topic, TopicSearchQuery> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getNamedParams(TopicSearchQuery query)
```

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense, I thought maybe I can somehow cheat and avoid adding one more generic to the class level. I know that I can define generic type on the method level and then used as type parameter in method args.

Comment: @IhorM. Try it, but I doubt it will work like you are hoping.

Comment: Your suggestion is a working solution but it doesn't really fit in my case because I'll end up having too many generics and it will become cumbersome to the user of my framework.

Comment: Here is my idea: 
` Map<String, Object> getNamedParams(SearchQuery<V> query, Class<? extends SearchQuery<V>> clazz);`

Comment: @IhorM. how do you get a `Class<? extends SearchQuery<V>>`?